# Removing duplicate labels within a given radius in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

In my map, every street segment is an entity. So each one is labelled as you can see in the picture. I'm trying to remove duplicate street labels within a given radius in QGIS, but I can't find how to do it. I know how to do it [in ArcGIS](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/removing-duplicate-labels-within-a-given-radius.htm), but in QGIS I cannot find the option.

[image: Street labels]

Comment: How do you do it in ArcGIS?

Comment: In the label options there is a check box for removing duplicate with an option to set a distance reference:  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/removing-duplicate-labels-within-a-given-radius.htm

Comment: group the line segments should help

Comment: @iant Can't do that... I have 45 588 segments. The image only show a small part of the map.

Comment: @Rashomon keep digging, there are many options that should clean this up, ie. labeling only line segments of a certain length, not labeling duplicate features, etc.

Comment: Grouping is a single tick box, http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/ca/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/label_tool.html#moderate-fa-labeling-lines

Comment: ... and the repeat option is in the placement tab ...

Answer (score 1):

You could use the vector > geoprocessing tools > dissolve tool. Make sure to put the field that you want to use as a label in the "dissolve field".This will give you a single line for each unique value in that field.

Then you can label the output layer as usual and put the desired radius that you'd use in ArGIS in the 'repeat' box of the labels tab of the layer properties.